# When can i break lines in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, line-breaks

sorry for the newbie question. I have this code, but i dont like it, its not very readable. I'm completely new to this and i'm not able to find an answer. I would like to spread the part following the append over multiple lines, but what is the correct syntax for this?

```
'buildHtml': function(data) {
    $('.visibility-attributes').append('<div class="div-table-row js-table-row"><div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell">Bestand</div><div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell-bolt"><span class="tab-product-attribute-name">' + data.stock.stocklevel + '</span></div></div><div class="div-table-row js-table-row"><div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell">Bestellbar</div><div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell-bolt"><span class="tab-product-attribute-name">' + data.stock.orderable + '</span></div></div>');
},
```

Comment: It looks like you might have confused Java with Javascript. They are different languages.

Comment: `"blah blah" (newline) +"more blah"`...

Comment: That being said, you generally shouldn't have that much HTML in your JavaScript files...

Comment: you can use the ` (the button left of 1 on standard uk  qwerty keyboards) instead of the single quote and do it over multiple lines - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Sorry for the wrong language, yes, i meant JS.

Thank you all for your fast answers, i will check out if i can find another way to use less html in JS, maybe one of my colleagues can help me. Thank you very much again, much appreciated <3

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for this

```
    var myHtmlString = "<div class='div-table-row js-table-row'>\
    <div class='div-table-cell js-div-table-cell'>\
    Bestand\
    </div>\
    <div class='div-table-cell js-div-table-cell-bolt'>\
    <span class='tab-product-attribute-name'>" + data.stock.stocklevel + "</span>\
    </div>\
    </div>\
<div class='div-table-row js-table-row'>\
    <div class='div-table-cell js-div-table-cell'>Bestellbar</div>\
    <div class='div-table-cell js-div-table-cell-bolt'>\
    <span class='tab-product-attribute-name'>" + data.stock.orderable + "</span>\
    </div>\
    </div>";

$('.visibility-attributes').append(myHtmlString )
```

Just write a backslash char at the end of every new line to consider the whole thing as one string. (Prevents head ache from + and "" )

Alternatively :

You can write the structure in a hidden div (as a template)

and fill the values in required html elements and copy the template to output div

```
$("#hiddenDiv").find(".tab-product-attribute-name").html(data.stock.stocklevel);
//blah
//blah
$('.visibility-attributes').append($("#hiddenDiv").html());
```

Comment: Points for most elegant solution! :) You could also, rather than having a element filled with html. Use one element, with many contextualised data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to replace the single quote ' with `

```html
'buildHtml': function(data) {
    $('.visibility-attributes').append(`
    <div class="div-table-row js-table-row">
       <div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell">Bestand</div>
       <div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell-bolt">
         <span class="tab-product-attribute-name">${data.stock.stocklevel}</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row js-table-row">
       <div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell">Bestellbar</div>
       <div class="div-table-cell js-div-table-cell-bolt">
         <span class="tab-product-attribute-name">${data.stock.orderable}</span>
       </div>
    </div>
 `);
},
```

Comment: Note that template literals like this will not work at all in any version of IE

Comment: you can use Babel in IE : ) @Rory McCrossan